# SQL Oracle get data with more of one associated data

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a table with some data like this:

```
|   cod_1   |   cod_2   |
-------------------------
|   1       |   03      |
|   2       |   07      |
|   2       |   09      |
|   3       |   09      |
|   4       |   01      |
|   4       |   02      |
|   4       |   08      |
```

In this case I need to get the cod_1 **2** and **4** because they have more tahn one cod_2 associated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT cod_1
FROM tablename
GROUP BY cod_1
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thk aF. Sorry I should say that my table has other fields, not just cod_1 and cod_2

Comment: But you just want to display cod_1?

Comment: Yes, but I need to group other fields too. Sorry my example was not enough detailed.